# jQuery UI Slider on iOS 10

Tags: ios, jquery-ui, slider, ios10, jquery-ui-slider

I have a problem with jQuery UI Slider in iOS 10.

I have a calculator which is included via iframe. It has horizontal sliders and form fields. The problem is: when I tap on slider line or on handle the page jumps or scrolls down, but when I go up and move handle it works fine. Then if I tap another slider the page scrolls down again. Every other form field works great. The problem only on iOS 10, the 9th version and android works fine. If I open the page with calculator alone it works fine. Any ideas?